# How to add a custom theme in Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, themes

In my react project I'm using Material UI as my component library. So, I'm having my own color pallet for the project. Since Material UI provides a default theme I have to modify that theme to my one. So what I did was add a theme and added that theme to themeProvider. After all, I wrapped my app.js with the theme provider. But it's not working.

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route} from "react-router-dom";
import ApplyPage from "./pages/Home/Home";
import SubmitPage from "./pages/submit/submit";
import StatusPage from "./pages/status/status";
import NotificationPanel from "./pages/notification/NotificationPanel";
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";
import ProfilePage from "./pages/profile/Profile";

function App() {
  const theme = createTheme({
    pallette: {
      primary: {
        main: "#2A9D8F",
      },
      secondary: {
        main: "#264653",
      },
    },
  });

  return (
    
    
      <Router>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<ApplyPage />} />
          <Route path="/submit" element={<SubmitPage />} />
          <Route path="/status" element={<StatusPage />} />
          <Route path="/notification" element={<NotificationPanel />} />
          <Route path="/profile" element={<ProfilePage />} />
        </Routes>
        </ThemeProvider>
      </Router>
    
    
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: try moving the createTheme outside the App component

Answer (score 0):

The method is right. The error is misspelling the `pallete` in there. The correct one is `palette`.